# Solve a system of SDEs

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

**The Question:**

If I have the following system of SDEs

$$ dX = (\beta + BX)dt + \sigma dW(t) $$

where $X(t)$ is a $d$-dimensional process, $W(t)$ is a $d$-dimensional Wiener process, $B$ a $d$-by-$d$ matrix and $\beta$ a $d$-dimensional column vector, how do I go about solving it?

**My thoughts so far:**

Can I break up the SDE into parts like:

$$ \int_0^tdX = \int_0^t\beta ds + \int_0^tBX(s)ds + \int_0^t\sigma dW(s) $$

Now I know that when we have a system of ODEs of the form $dx = Axdt$ for some matrix $A$ we get the solution $x(t) = e^{At}x(0)$, but I can't work out how to use this fact in this case.

Does this imply $X(t) = X(0)(\beta t + e^{Bt} + \sigma W(t))$? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y= e^{-Bt}X$. Then

$$ dY = e^{-Bt}(\beta dt+ \sigma dW_t)
$$
Integrate

$$Y=Y_0 + \int_0^t\beta e^{-Bs}ds + \int_0^t\sigma e^{-Bs}dW_s
$$

Thus, the solution is

$$X = e^{Bt}X_0+ \int_0^t\beta e^{B(t-s)}ds + \int_0^t\sigma e^{B(t-s)} dW_s
$$

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of using an integrating factor, very clever. However, shouldn't there be a factor of $e^{Bt}$ multiplying the $X_0$? Also can the integrals in the solution be evaluated if we assume that B is a constant matrix?

Comment: @R.Rayl - you’re right about the factor times $X_0$. The first integral can be evaluated as $\frac {\beta}B (e^{Bt}-1)$